# Данный алгоритм не выводит все подстроки в слове

Tags: c#, алгоритм, методы, системное-программирование, трансляция

Проблема заключается в том, что алгоритм не выводит все строки в слове. Если у нас есть строка с удаленными префиксом и суффиксом, то должно сперва вывести одинарные буквы, потом подстроки из двух, из трех и так далее. Прошу подсказать что не так.На картинке показано результаты работы метода.

```
public List<string> GetSubstring(List<string> words)
        {
            HashSet<string> SetSubstrings = new HashSet<string>();
            string removed = "";
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                SetSubstrings.Add("Подстроки слова " + word);
                removed = word.Remove(0, 1);
                removed = removed.Remove(removed.Length - 1);
                for (int i = 0; i < removed.Length; i++)
                {
                    string substring = removed.Substring(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < removed.Length-i; j++)
                    {
                        SetSubstrings.Add(substring);
                        substring = substring.Substring(1);
                    }
                }
                removed = "";
            }

            return SetSubstrings.ToList();
        }
```

[image: Вывод на данный момент]

Comment: В обоих операциях отрезания у строки отрезаются префиксы. В результат попадают только суффиксы исходной строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чето как то сложно у вас всё. Чтобы пробежать по всем подстрокам в порядке длины подстроки, достаточно всего пары циклов. Пример

```
void SubStrings(string word)
{
    for (int len = 1; len <= word.Length; len++)
        for (int start = 0; (start + len) <= word.Length; start++)
            Console.WriteLine(word.Substring(start, len));
}
```

Проверка

```
SubStrings("Geshtalt");
```

Результат

```
G
e
s
h
t
a
l
t
Ge
es
sh
ht
ta
al
lt
Ges
esh
sht
hta
tal
alt
Gesh
esht
shta
htal
talt
Gesht
eshta
shtal
htalt
Geshta
eshtal
shtalt
Geshtal
eshtalt
Geshtalt
```

Чтобы убрать дубликаты, используйте Хешсет. Но имейте ввиду, что хешсет не гарантирует порядок элементов.